# Loading Nested Json File In Spark Dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am loading data from json file to my dataframe when i am doing df.show i am able to see column name but its a nested json file so there are many subcolumn are also there
can anyone plese guide me how can see all the column and values.

```
     A: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- d: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- e: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- f: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- g: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- j: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- k: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- l: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- m: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- n: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- e: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- j: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rt: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- o: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- p: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- ok: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- ol: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- o: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- tabname: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- p: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- q: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- val: double (nullable = true)
     |-- r: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |-- s: string (nullable = true)
     |-- t: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |-- u: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |-- v: long (nullable = true)
     |-- w: string (nullable = true)
     |-- x: long (nullable = true)
     |-- y: string (nullable = true)
     |-- z: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ab: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ac: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ad: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- ek: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- bb: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- doclst: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ec: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ei: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- oi: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- rbb: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ada: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ek: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ik: string (nullable = true)
     |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ek: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- e: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- j: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- o: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ccc: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ik: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- e: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- j: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- o: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- rk: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- tk: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- e: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- j: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- o: long (nullable = true)
     |-- lt: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- ff: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- zz: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- yy: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- xx: string (nullable = true)
     |-- za: long (nullable = true)
     |-- zb: string (nullable = true)
     |-- zc: long (nullable = true)
```

when i am doing df.show i am able to see only Address but not adle to see(full_Address,Address1,Address2 etc).

i am writing below code.

```
    val sampledata = sparksession.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles(filepath).values)
    sampledata.select(($"Address").as("Address")).show
```

Comment: can you give valid json as an example? Above json example is invalid.
Nested Json can parsed in Struct datatype.

Comment: what is your expected output ??

Comment: can you show your dataframe print schema ??

Comment: spark expect a "flat" JSON. Meaning lines of Structs separated by a comma. One line is one row.

Answer (score 2):

`Address` is of type `struct`, You need to extract columns from `Address` column to see other columns.

Check below code

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- Address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Address1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Hno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- street: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Address2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Hno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- street: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Address3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Hno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- street: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- full_Address: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df.select("Address.*").printSchema
root
 |-- Address1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Hno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Address2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Hno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Address3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Hno: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: long (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- full_Address: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df.select("Address.*").show(false)
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+
|Address1         |Address2             |Address3         |country|full_Address|
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+
|[7, 462036, 1, 5]|[0, 462037, 0, 25578]|[0, 462038, 0, 0]|India  |112018      |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------+------------+
```

```
cala> val expr = array((1 to 3).map(c => array(struct(lit(s"Address${c}").as("address_no"),col(s"Address.Address${c}").as("address_details"),col("Address.country"),col("Address.full_Address")))):_*)

scala>  df.withColumn("address",explode(expr)).select(explode($"address").as("address")).select($"address.address_no",$"address.address_details.*",$"address.country",$"address.full_Address").show(false)
+----------+---+------+-----+------+-------+------------+
|address_no|Hno|pin   |state|street|country|full_Address|
+----------+---+------+-----+------+-------+------------+
|Address1  |7  |462036|1    |5     |India  |112018      |
|Address2  |0  |462037|0    |25578 |India  |112018      |
|Address3  |0  |462038|0    |0     |India  |112018      |
+----------+---+------+-----+------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas I tried df.select("Address.*").show(false)  but its not  showing values of Hno,pin state street. Then i tried using df.select("Address.Address1.*","Address.Address2.*") but in case its creating samecolumn 2 times like.Hno,pin state street,Hno,pin state street. is there any way to create these column only one time and for diff values i.e. for address1.hno,address2.Hno i can store in rows.

Comment: you need to rename columns inside  ```Address1``` & ```Address2``` .. as these columns has same columns inside when you extract it will create sample columns.

Comment: yes Thanks a lot @Srinivas Your Solution worked for me.need one more information instead of Address1,Address1,Address1 if i have all diffenent names like.(per_add,temp_addres,communition_ad) then how should i process.

Comment: Add your complete schema in question I will check and update solution based on that

Comment: I have Updated my Question and shared my exact schema.I have just changed to column name but the structure is same.

Comment: in this sachema if u see u will find one address and inside address(ek,ik,rk,tk and ccc) are there.and againg inside (ek,ik,tk) again(e,h,j,o) column are there i want to store all these column in my dataframe like.ek.e,ek.h,ek.j,ek.o,ik.e,ik.h,ik.j,ik.o,tk.e,tk.h,tk.j,tk.o. so it should create these 12 diff columns in df